# how to calculate week number for date type "dd-mm-yy" in jquery-ui datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

i have used jquery-ui datepicker in my application. I want to count a week number with date type "dd-mm-yy" but it giving me a wrong week number i realize that it uses "mm-dd-yy" date type to calculate week number.

i have used bellow code :

```
<input type="text" class="calendar">
<input type="text" class="week">

$(function() {
$(".calendar").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
showWeek: true,
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
dateFormat: "'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)),
$(".week").val('Week:' + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
}

});
$(".calendar").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

[here is a also a JSFiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/Zala/cqzhcbh1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inst` to get `selectedYear`, `selectedMonth` and `selectedDay` and construct a `Date` from those values instead of the `dateText`.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showWeek: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var newDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
      dateFormat: "'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(newDate),
        $(".week").val('Week:' + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(newDate));
    }
  });
  $(".calendar").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqzhcbh1/1/).

Answer (score 0):

add this link to JSFiddle resources

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.js

now run this code only

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var weekday = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
    alert(weekday);
  });
```